# Tab view on landingpage?

Tags: layout, css, programming

On the product lasting pages there is the tab view. Is it possible to create custom tabs on landingpages? A bit like this https://www.decalgirl.com/custom/cases - this is not my page, just like the tabs they have on it.

Will this be a big project for a programmer to make or?

Answer (score 1):

And with some other search terms i was able to find out by myself :)

I took this and put that in the head: (app/design/frontend/your_package/your_theme/template/page/html/head.phtml)
This is only for the page with the title

```
<?php
$headBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head');
if ($headBlock->getModuleName() == 'Mage_Page' && $headBlock->getTitle() == 'test'): // remember from above step # 1 that the page title is set as 'Testing'
?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">jQuery.noConflict();</script>  
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function() {
        jQuery( "#tabs" ).tabs();
    });
</script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Then on the page created called test

```
<div style="float: right; width: 200px;">
<p>{{block type="tag/popular" template="tag/popular.phtml"}}</p>
</div>
<div id="tabs" style="width: 680px;">
<ul>
<li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs-1">
<p>Your content?</p>
</div>
<div id="tabs-2">
<p>Your content?</p>
</div>
<div id="tabs-3">
<p>Your content?</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Source:
http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-add-jquery-tabs-in-cms-page/
http://jqueryui.com/tabs

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Ok thx Marius :) I will edit it :)